# Printing Out a Message by Action with Mvc.Controller? VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

### The Controller

---

```
Public Class HelloWorldController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /HelloWorldController

    Function PrintMessage() As ActionResult


    End Function

End Class
```

### The URL Request

---

`http:// localhost:1430 / HelloWorld / PrintMessage`

### The Question

---

How can one print out a message in the web browser on the localhost, with the above used "Mvc.Controller", the method and the corresponding URL request?

The method (the action) is `intended` to become invoked by simply pressing a link or a button.

Comment: Create a view to hold your message

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Coming from a PHP background I am getting to know the _principles_ of VB.NET. I did create a view (VBHTML) and have the messages written there. Now it takes calling it up with a request. By the _default principle_ it is the `HomeController`. Thus the URL request looks as follows: `http://localhost:1430/Home/TheMessageView`. The view holds two messages, individually in a headline tag and a paragraph tag.

Comment: For further clarification, how would have the parameter part of the `URL request` to look like to request just the `HTML tag` and its content it holds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method to return a string:

```
return Content("Hello World")
```

If you want formatting, then create a view and return the string as your model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have a closer look at it. I have just written a comment above, to this topic.